# What is $\mathrm{sup}\{4x-2y:x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2<4\}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I'm currently working on an assignment where I have to find the supremum of $\{4x-2y:x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2<4\}$. Please don't give me the solution, just some ideas as to how I can work this out.

Comment: Try finding the maximum value of $f(x,y) = 4x-2y$ in the closed disk $\lbrace (x, y) : x^2 + y^2 \leq 4 \rbrace$.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/utmjksofys

Comment: Thank you, I think I've got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $s$ the value of the supremum. $4x-2y=s$ is an equation for a line. The point $x,y$ is part of the disk. You get a maximum or minimum value for $s$ when the line is tangent to the disk